# 'com.omondo.uml.core' and 'com.omondo.uml.std' register a package for 'editmodel.xmi' --> eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I got since a few day an error log. And after 3 days inquest google&co. plus stackoverflow I cannot resolve it!
So your are my last hope! I'm using **Eclipse Juno** and developing a plugin.

That's the error:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2 0 2013-11-15 15:48:16.772 !MESSAGE Both
>   'com.omondo.uml.core' and 'com.omondo.uml.std' register a package for
>   'editmodel.xmi'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look into the plugin.xml and check for extension points featuring packages with the same **uri**.